# Rest API - Term Store - Unexpected response from the service

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, managed-metadata, power-automate, term-store

I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIVmvFcQYmk&lc=UgyU12jRh89gXivRyMx4AaABAg.9O6kluxXSIp9O7pmC8uffx, in order to get terms by name from Term Store in SharePoint, but I got this error:

> Unexpected response from the service clientRequestId: 984cc7f7-59dd-4420-8230-d042c5588864 serviceRequestId: a707f19f-a009-c000-7508-128edec78063

When I use this API:

```
_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/TERMGROUPID/sets/TERMSETID/terms?$select=id,labels
```

Actually what I need to do is get the terms from local term set, and I thought that maybe I need to change something in the API for example grab the unique id about Site Collection before the id's about term group and term set but I couldn't find any reliable API.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: At what minute in the video? Can you post a screenshot of what you were trying to do? If you go to "_api" page in sharepoint, what do you get? As in contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/testcol/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/TERMGROUPID/sets/TERMSETID/terms?$select=id,labels/ what do you get back?